# db2 explain stored procedure

Tags: db2, explain, ibm-data-studio

How to explain stored procedure in IBM Data Studio?

I know that there exist `db2expln` command. But I want a solution to explain the SP in graphical interface.

Also I know that selecting a query and then right clicking on it, there exists `open visual explain` menu do the explain but don't know the way to explain SP in order that I can set input values for that SP.

thanks

Comment: Input values normally does not affect the plan (reopt ignored). Are you looking for a way to debug your sp? As a side note, db2exfmt is in my opinion a better tool than db2expln.

Comment: Actually I don't want to debug, I just to have a explain of the SP and if I explain it with query inside the body of SP the it would have error because of input parameters using in body. It's a complicated SP with so many cursors and parameters using inside other selects

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to explain a query in your procedure you can replace the in-parameters with parameter markers (?). Then do an explain of that query.

Comment: Would you please explain about parameter marker with an example as an answer. I think this is the answer of my question. I'll be so much thankful if you have an example in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirements correctly you have a procedure where you would like to explain the plan for a query inside that procedure. I'll invent some bogus stuff to explain my thoughts:

```
create table t 
(  x int not null primary key
,  y int not null) @

create procedure p (n int)
language sql
begin
    declare c cursor for
    select count(1) from t where y = n;
end @
```

Assuming you would like to explain the plan for the query in the cursor:

```
db2 "explain plan for select count(1) from t where y = n"
[...]
SQL0206N  "N" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703
```

Since n is not bound the compiler will complain. However, changing n to a host variable or a parameter marker will be fine (note the ":" )

```
db2 "explain plan for select count(1) from t where y = :n"
```

or:

```
db2 "explain plan for select count(1) from t where y = ?"
```

Now you can use db2exfmt to look at the plan:

```
db2exfmt -d sample -g -1 | tee q.plan

Access Plan:
-----------
Total Cost:         0.00644873
Query Degree:       1

            Rows 
           RETURN
           (   1)
            Cost 
             I/O 
             |
              1 
           GRPBY 
           (   2)
          0.0063121 
              0 
             |
              0 
           FETCH 
           (   3)
         0.00627372 
              0 
       /-----+-----\
      0               0 
   IXSCAN    TABLE:    LELLE   
   (   4)             T
 0.00613403          Q1
      0 
     |
      0 
INDEX:    SYSIBM  
SQL141230182649950
        Q1
```

I think you will find `db2exfmt` a much better tool than `db2expln`, you will get a lot more details for your plan.

Comment: Parameter marker solved my problem. Thanks so much. Just one thing more. For `db2explain` I highlighted the query and right click on it and then click on `open visual explain` (In graphical interface-IBM visual studio). How can I do `db2exfmt` in graphical interface?

Comment: I might have misunderstood you. `db2expln` is a command line tool, the same goes for `db2exfmt` so you probably can't run `db2exfmt` from the   graphical interface (I use only the command line tools myself, so I don't know for sure). The good news is that the visual explain uses the same internal mechanisms as `db2exfmt` so you will probably get the same amount of detail there.

Comment: Sorry for asking so much questions. Do you know what is `Lock list size` and `Maximum Lock List size` in explain result?

Comment: That is db cfg parameters (db2 get db cfg), but it is slightly off topic so it is probably best to start a new question about that.

Comment: I asked my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717317/db2-explain-result-about-lock-size). Will be so much glad if you answer any idea of yourself.