# db2 explain result about lock size

Tags: db2, explain, ibm-data-studio

What is `Lock List Size`, `Maximum Lock List Size` and `Locks Available` in the result of explain using IBM data studio.

[image]

I read some sources from IBM but can not understand the complete concept and different between those.

Please tell any resources about these attributes (also others in the attribute pane)

Thanks

Comment: Since I don't use visual explain I can only guess. You can verify the following hypothesis by `db2 get db cfg for <db> show detail` and `db2 get snapshot for db on <db>`. I guess Lock list size is `Lock list memory in use (Bytes)` (see snapshot). Maximum lock list size is `MAXLOCKS, Percent. of lock lists per application` (see db cfg) and Locks available is `LOCKLIST, Max storage for lock list (4KB) blocks  -  Lock list size`. But this is only guessing on my behalf. You may also want to compare with the output from db2exfmt, under Database context it lists locking related info (other names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lennart,

Lock list size is Lock list memory in use (Bytes) (see snapshot).

Maximum lock list size is MAXLOCKS, Percent. of lock lists per application (see db cfg) and Locks available is LOCKLIST, Max storage for lock list (4KB) blocks - Lock list size.